# Create a dynamic table based on occurrences in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a problem i cannot solve.

I'm trying to create a table that creates multiple lines per order based on the number of shipments. so for example the data i download has 2 columns, order no. and shipments.

if the shipments is more than 1 then i need a sperate line for each shipment in my new table.

I will attach a picture of what I'm trying to achieve. it has stumped me!

I've search hi and low but can't find an answer, perhaps its my clumsy wording when searching? :)

ideally i want to achieve this using formulas so data can just be copy and pasted in, thought i guess i can use vba if i must.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, then one could use the following formula and for the given sample this should clearly work:*

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, SEQUENCE(,MAX(B3:B6)), MID(TOCOL(IF(α>B3:B6,0/0,A3:A6&" "&α),3),{1,3},{1,1}))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, SEQUENCE(,MAX(B3:B6)),
     δ, TOCOL(IF(α>B3:B6,0/0,A3:A6&" "&α),3),
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(δ," "),--TEXTAFTER(δ," ")))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)` and what I see it will be easier & simpler to achieve using the said tool.

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps: (Read the steps annotations to follow)

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_ONE`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Ship-ments", each {1..[shipments]}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Ship-ments"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"shipments"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

**Edit** Per tags it shows `Excel 2010` then can use `POWER QUERY` or using helper columns with `VLOOKUP()` & `COUNTIF()`

[image]

---

- In <kbd>A3</kbd> enter `1`
- In <kbd>A4</kbd> enter `=A3+C3` and copy down till the one extra last row of your data
- Next use `VLOOKUP()` in cell <kbd>E3</kbd> & `COUNTIF()` in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

---

```
=VLOOKUP(ROW(A1),$A$3:$B$7,2,1)
```

---

```
=COUNTIF(E$3:E3,E3)
```

---

and drag down as far as it needs to go.

---

Comment: thank you, that answer was incredible! :)